# wp_editor mce-view

Tags: tinymce, wp-editor, embed, oembed

We are using the `wp_editor` on a page on the front-end to allow subscribers to create a cpt post.

We added support for auto-turning youtube urls into embed tags:

```
function mce_scripts() {    
    wp_enqueue_script( 'mce-view' );    
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'mce_scripts' );
```

It works - but only for site administrators. How can we get it to work for users who are *not* site administrators?

We don't want to give subscribers the `add_posts` capability, so perhaps it is a permissions issue?

Comment: can you expand your code? I can only see one line but there's no context for it such as when where and how it's being enqueued, or where and how `wp_editor` is being called/used beyond frontend/backend

Comment: Please see edits.

Comment: I don't see `mce-view` listed in WordPress's [list of default scripts](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/contributors/code/scripts/); have you already registered it somewhere? Is it registered in a way that checks to see if the user is a site admin, eg, `current_user_can( 'manage_options' )`?

Comment: I have not registered it anywhere.  I simply enqueue as shown above. Not sure what is actually enqueued. But it is limited to administrators - so something is checking the current user.  But I cannot figure out what or where that check is located.  If not enqueued, site admins cannot auto-embed video urls.  Any hints appreciated.

Comment: @PatJ - It is found in  `wp-includes\js\mce-view.js`.  It is loaded in  `wp-includes\script-loader.php` on Line 1394.  I still cannot find the permissions restriction.